# How to rewrite/extend a Magento class in an existing third party extension

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to extend the class of a third party Magento extension.

**My module xml:**

within config>modules> tags

```
<EDPA_MegaNavigation>

        <active>true</active>

        <codePool>local</codePool>

        <depends>
            <Infortis_UltraMegamenu />
        </depends>

    </EDPA_MegaNavigation>
```

**My Config xml:**

within config>global>blocks> tags

```
 <ultramegamenu>

       <rewrite>

           <Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Block_Navigation>EDPA_MegaNavigation_Block_Navigation</Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Block_Navigation>

       </rewrite>

   </ultramegamenu>
```

**My extended class** (Navigation.php) has

```
class EDPA_MegaNavigation_Block_Navigation extends Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Block_Navigation
{
########
}
```

Within system>configuration>advanced EDPA_MegaNavigation is listed and shows as enabled.

My target navigation.php within Infortis>UltraMegamenu>Block is not being rewritten.

Any help/guidance much appreciated.

Comment: put Infortis>UltraMegamenu >etc>config.xml for works

Comment: in which codepool your ultramegamenu module is located? in local or community?

Comment: local codepool - but please check Amit Bera's answer as this got my extension working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the issue in 
if Infortis_UltraMegamenu module block tag is   `ultramegamenu` then

```
<ultramegamenu>

       <rewrite>

           <navigation>EDPA_MegaNavigation_Block_Navigation</navigation>

       </rewrite>

   </ultramegamenu>
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed my <Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Block_Navigation> tag to <navigation>, refreshed the browser, worked. Thank you Amit Bera!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<rewrite>` doesn't look to be set up properly, it's supposed to reference another config node and not a direct class name.  Check the UltraMegamenu's `config.xml` to get the node from it.

e.g. If UltraMegamenu is set up like:

```
<blocks>
    <ultramegamenu>
        <class>Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Block_Navigation</class>
    </ultramegamenu>
</blocks>
```

Then your rewrite child node would be "ultramegamenu" instead of the class name.